# Tomcat default servlet (/) lose css

Tags: java, css, tomcat, servlets

I have a small issue with tomcat. If I map my default servlet (named Index) to /, the css inside the jsp page will not be displayed, so for the moment we can access to the main page by /Index.

The css include is : `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ressources/design.css" />`
(folder ressources at the same level than WEB-INF)

I'm probably wrong on the css call, isn't it?

Thanks for your reply

Tom

Comment: are you sure it's "ressources" instead of "resources" ?

Comment: are you sure it's not a context issue and have you tried `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ressources/design.css" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat's default Servlet handles all static resources. If you replace Tomcat's default Servlet with your own then you have effectively disabled Tomcat's support for static resources and you'll have to replace it.

You have a couple of options.

1. Implement static resource handling in your own default Servlet.
2. Modify / extend Tomcat's default servlet to add whatever functionality is in your default Servlet.
3. Remap Tomcat's default servlet e.g. to /ressources and place all your static resources under that directory.

The best option depends on what your own default Servlet is doing.

Comment: Yes of course, I did the 3 one, my index.jsp doesn't need a servlet...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Place it in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources/ressources/design.css` if you have a web.xml-version 3.0.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but my web.xml seems to be version 1.0